# Can I create a "view" on a Python list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice

I have a large list `l`. I want to create a view from element 4 to 6. I can do it with sequence slice.

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> lv = l[3:6]
>>> lv
[3, 4, 5]
```

However `lv` is a copy of a slice of `l`. If I change the underlying list, `lv` does not reflect the change.

```
>>> l[4] = -1
>>> lv
[3, 4, 5]
```

Vice versa I want modification on `lv` reflect in `l` as well. Other than that the list size are not going to be changed.

I'm not looking forward to build a big class to do this. I'm just hoping other Python gurus may know some hidden language trick. Ideally I hope it can be like pointer arithmetic in C:

```c
int lv[] = l + 3;
```

Comment: @robert How? The `memoryview` works only for objects with buffer interface and list is not one of them.

Comment: In the example provided here you should use a `bytearray` instead of a list. You may also wrap the list in `bytearray`.

Comment: The [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html), since the `memoryview` docs don't link to it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no "list slice" class in the Python standard library (nor is one built-in).  So, you do need a class, though it need not be big -- especially if you're content with a "readonly" and "compact" slice.  E.g.:

```
import collections

class ROListSlice(collections.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, alist, start, alen):
        self.alist = alist
        self.start = start
        self.alen = alen

    def __len__(self):
        return self.alen

    def adj(self, i):
        if i<0: i += self.alen
        return i + self.start

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.alist[self.adj(i)]
```

This has some limitations (doesn't support "slicing a slice") but for most purposes might be OK.

To make this sequence r/w you need to add `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, and `insert`:

```
class ListSlice(ROListSlice):

    def __setitem__(self, i, v):
        self.alist[self.adj(i)] = v

    def __delitem__(self, i, v):
        del self.alist[self.adj(i)]
        self.alen -= 1

    def insert(self, i, v):
        self.alist.insert(self.adj(i), v)
        self.alen += 1
```

Comment: Could you do something like `def __slice__(self, *args, **kwargs): return (self.alist[self.start:self.start+self.alen]).__slice__(*args, **kwargs)` to support things like slicing? Basically passing through the request to a slice created on-demand.

Comment: But if you do `alist.insert(0, something)` the slice moves! That might or might not be a problem ...

Comment: @Amber, `__slice__` is not a special method in Python.  Slicing results in calls to `__getindex__`, `__setindex__`, `__delindex__`, so you'd have to typecheck and adjust that (easier for the getting, as your approach will delegate things OK -- harder for setting and deleting, though).

Comment: @THC4k, yes, of course -- there's all sorts of issues about what happens for many kinds of alterations to the underlying list -- e.g., what if you `del alist[:]` leaving it empty, the slice will still think it's got a certain length -- &c. To "trap" all possible such alterations would require wrapping the list (and you can't assign its `__class__`) and mucho code _and_ design decisions. But the OP says "the list size are not going to be changed" (he says "other than that" but the examples before then don't change list size either) so insert, del and pop are probably irrelevant to the OP.

Comment: @Alex: Hm. I could have sworn that there were ways to override slicing (say, to allow for things like 2-dimensional slicing). But I could be wrong. :)

Comment: @Amber, of course you can "override slicing" -- you do that by overriding `__getitem__` (and maybe the set and del ones as well, for a type with mutable instances), and type-checking / type-switching on the "index" argument (e.g., to allow `a[1:2,3:4]`, you deal with receiving, as the "index" argument, a tuple with two items, both of them slice objects).

Comment: @Alex - that's basically what I was getting at, then - the `__slice__` bit was just something that popped to mind; but it seems like you could do the same with slicing (just override `__getitem__` to operate on the generated slice instead of the original list).

Comment: @Amber, while that can work for `__getitem__` (slowly, as it makes a redundant slice for every indexing, and `collections.Sequence` uses indexing a _lot_ -- look at its sources), it can't for `__setitem__`, and it would be truly weird if you could get but not set a slice.  So, for a mutable sequence, you do have to perform type-checking and adjustments (probably in the `def adj`, so at least you need code them only once, but it's still somewhat delicate code and the OP said he didn't want "a big class";-) -- for an immutable one, only if you care at all about performance.

Comment: Thanks. It is neat to break down into a RO class and a RW class. No I don't need to insert or delete from the list. If this becomes a requirement it will turn into a whole new topic.

Comment: @Wai, you're welcome!  Yes, using the ABCs in `collections`, for implementing each of sequences, sets, and mappings, often turns into a pair of X / MutableX (where the latter can usefully inherit from the former), which can be handy.

Answer (score 32):

Perhaps just use a numpy array:

```
In [19]: import numpy as np

In [20]: l=np.arange(10)
```

Basic slicing numpy arrays [returns a view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing), not a copy:

```
In [21]: lv=l[3:6]

In [22]: lv
Out[22]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

Altering `l` affects `lv`:

```
In [23]: l[4]=-1

In [24]: lv
Out[24]: array([ 3, -1,  5])
```

And altering `lv` affects `l`:

```
In [25]: lv[1]=4

In [26]: l
Out[26]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do that by creating your own generator using the original list reference.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
lv = (l[i] for i in range(1,4))

lv.next()   # 2
l[2]=-1
lv.next()   # -1
lv.next()   # 4
```

However this being a generator, you can only go through the list once, forwards and it will explode if you remove more elements than you requested with `range`.

Answer (score 7):

Subclass the [`more_itertools.SequenceView`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.SequenceView) to affect views by mutating sequences and vice versa.

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


class SequenceView(mit.SequenceView):
    """Overload assignments in views."""
    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        self._target[index] = item
```

**Demo**

```
>>> seq = list(range(10))
>>> view = SequenceView(seq)
>>> view
SequenceView([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

>>> # Mutate Sequence -> Affect View
>>> seq[6] = -1
>>> view[5:8]
[5, -1, 7]

>>> # Mutate View -> Affect Sequence
>>> view[5] = -2
>>> seq[5:8]
[-2, -1, 7]
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library.  Install via `> pip install more_itertools`.

Comment: plus one for making me discover `more_itertools`, though I won't be using your code

Comment: No worries.  `more_itertools` is a great toolbox.  I encourage people to explore it.

Answer (score 6):

https://gist.github.com/mathieucaroff/0cf094325fb5294fb54c6a577f05a2c1

Above link is a solution based on python 3 range ability to be sliced and
indexed in constant time.

It supports slicing, equality comparsion, string casting (`__str__`), and
reproducers (`__repr__`), but doesn't support assigment.

Creating a SliceableSequenceView of a SliceableSequenceView won't slow down
access times as this case is detected.

#### sequenceView.py

```py
# stackoverflow.com/q/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list

try:
    from collections.abc import Sequence
except ImportError:
    from collections import Sequence # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module

class SliceableSequenceView(Sequence):
    """
    A read-only sequence which allows slicing without copying the viewed list.
    Supports negative indexes.

    Usage:
        li = list(range(100))
        s = SliceableSequenceView(li)
        u = SliceableSequenceView(li, slice(1,7,2))
        v = s[1:7:2]
        w = s[-99:-93:2]
        li[1] += 10
        assert li[1:7:2] == list(u) == list(v) == list(w)
    """
    __slots__ = "seq range".split()
    def __init__(self, seq, sliced=None):
        """
        Accept any sequence (such as lists, strings or ranges).
        """
        if sliced is None:
            sliced = slice(len(seq))
        ls = looksSliceable = True
        ls = ls and hasattr(seq, "seq") and isinstance(seq.seq, Sequence)
        ls = ls and hasattr(seq, "range") and isinstance(seq.range, range)
        looksSliceable = ls
        if looksSliceable:
            self.seq = seq.seq
            self.range = seq.range[sliced]
        else:
            self.seq = seq
            self.range = range(len(seq))[sliced]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.range)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            return SliceableSequenceView(self.seq, i)
        return self.seq[self.range[i]]

    def __str__(self):
        r = self.range
        s = slice(r.start, r.stop, r.step)
        return str(self.seq[s])

    def __repr__(self):
        r = self.range
        s = slice(r.start, r.stop, r.step)
        return "SliceableSequenceView({!r})".format(self.seq[s])

    def equal(self, otherSequence):
        if self is otherSequence:
            return True
        if len(self) != len(otherSequence):
            return False
        for v, w in zip(self, otherSequence):
            if v != w:
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you will take a slice from a list, you will be creating a new list. Ok, it will contain same objects so as long as objects of the list are concerned it would be the same, but if you modify a slice the original list is unchanged.

If you really want to create a modifiable view, you could imagine a new class based on `collection.MutableSequence`

This could be a starting point for a full featured sub list - it correctly processes slice indexes, but at least is lacking specification for negative indexes processing:

```
class Sublist(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, ls, beg, end):
        self.ls = ls
        self.beg = beg
        self.end = end
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        self._valid(i)
        return self.ls[self._newindex(i)]
    def __delitem__(self, i):
        self._valid(i)
        del self.ls[self._newindex(i)]
    def insert(self, i, x):
        self._valid(i)
        self.ls.insert(i+ self.beg, x)
    def __len__(self):
        return self.end - self.beg
    def __setitem__(self, i, x):
        self.ls[self._newindex(i)] = x
    def _valid(self, i):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            self._valid(i.start)
            self._valid(i.stop)
        elif isinstance(i, int):
            if i<0 or i>=self.__len__():
                raise IndexError()
        else:
            raise TypeError()
    def _newindex(self, i):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            return slice(self.beg + i.start, self.beg + i.stop, i.step)
        else:
            return i + self.beg
```

Example:

```
>>> a = list(range(10))
>>> s = Sublist(a, 3, 8)
>>> s[2:4]
[5, 6]
>>> s[2] = 15
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: This is a direct answer to another question that was closed as a duplicate from this one. As other answers from here were relevant, I prefered add it here

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** `The object argument must be an object that supports the buffer call interface (such as strings, arrays, and buffers).` - so no, sadly.

I think [buffer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422685/what-is-python-buffer-type-for) is what you are looking for.

Pasting example from linked page:

```
>>> s = bytearray(1000000)   # a million zeroed bytes
>>> t = buffer(s, 1)         # slice cuts off the first byte
>>> s[1] = 5                 # set the second element in s
>>> t[0]                     # which is now also the first element in t!
'\x05'
```

Comment: there is no `buffer()` builtin in Python 3. `memoryview()` could be used instead.

Comment: Also, this inspects the in memory bytes of the area  - Python lists do contain objects (which 'in memory' are pointer to the objects ) so - definetelly, this would be  a very wrong approach - One would have to use `ctypes` , and redo all the Pointer indirection work, as if he was coding in C,  that Python does for free

Answer (score 0):

You could ***edit: not*** do something like

```
shiftedlist = type('ShiftedList',
                   (list,),
                   {"__getitem__": lambda self, i: list.__getitem__(self, i + 3)}
                  )([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Being essentially a one-liner, it's not very Pythonic, but that's the basic gist.

***edit:*** I've belatedly realized that this doesn't work because `list()` will essentially do a shallow copy of the list it's passed.  So this will end up being more or less the same as just slicing the list.  Actually less, due to a missing override of `__len__`.  You'll need to use a proxy class; see [Mr. Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list/3485507#answer-3485490) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not too difficult to implement this yourself using `range`.*  You can slice a range and it does all of the complicated arithmetic for you:

```
>>> range(20)[10:]
range(10, 20)
>>> range(10, 20)[::2]
range(10, 20, 2)
>>> range(10, 20, 2)[::-3]
range(18, 8, -6)
```

So you just need a class of object that contains a reference to the original sequence, and a range. Here is the code for such a class (not too big, I hope):

```py
class SequenceView:

    def __init__(self, sequence, range_object=None):
        if range_object is None:
            range_object = range(len(sequence))
        self.range    = range_object
        self.sequence = sequence

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if type(key) == slice:
            return SequenceView(self.sequence, self.range[key])
        else:
            return self.sequence[self.range[key]]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.sequence[self.range[key]] = value

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.range)

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.range:
            yield self.sequence[i]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"SequenceView({self.sequence!r}, {self.range!r})"

    def __str__(self):
        if type(self.sequence) == str:
            return ''.join(self)
        elif type(self.sequence) in (list, tuple):
            return str(type(self.sequence)(self))
        else:
            return repr(self)
```

(This was bodged together in about 5 minutes, so make sure you test it thoroughly before using it anywhere important.)

Usage:

```py
>>> p = list(range(10))
>>> q = SequenceView(p)[3:6]
>>> print(q)
[3, 4, 5]
>>> q[1] = -1
>>> print(q)
[3, -1, 5]
>>> print(p)
[0, 1, 2, 3, -1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

* in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: The code is provided only for research purposes. I don't recommend using it.**

This is indeed possible in CPython.
You can "hack" into internal values and make a list refer to another list. This approach, however, is not reliable and may break at any time. It can also segfault if you change size of the view or do something wrong.

```
from ctypes import POINTER, cast, c_ssize_t, c_void_p, sizeof

SIZE_OFFSET = sizeof(c_ssize_t) + sizeof(c_void_p)
DATA_OFFSET = SIZE_OFFSET + sizeof(c_ssize_t)


def _get_size_pointer(obj):
    return cast(c_void_p(id(obj) + SIZE_OFFSET), POINTER(c_ssize_t))


def _get_data_pointer(obj):
    return cast(c_void_p(id(obj) + DATA_OFFSET), POINTER(c_void_p))


def listview_create(li, start, stop):
    size = len(li)

    new_li = []

    if stop <= 0 or start >= stop or start >= size:
        return new_li

    if stop > size:
        stop = size
    if start < 0:
        start = 0

    _get_size_pointer(new_li)[0] = stop - start
    _get_data_pointer(new_li)[0] = _get_data_pointer(li)[0] + sizeof(c_void_p) * start
    return new_li


def listview_destroy(view):
    _get_size_pointer(view)[0] = 0
    _get_data_pointer(view)[0] = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = list(range(10))

    lv = listview_create(l, 3, 6)
    print(lv)

    l[4] = -1
    print(lv)

    listview_destroy(lv)
```

Output (CPython 3.11):

```
[3, 4, 5]
[3, -1, 5]
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are going to be accessing the "view" sequentially then you can just use itertools.islice(..)[You can see the documentation for more info](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
d = [1:3] #[2, 3]
d = itertools.islice(2, 3) # iterator yielding -> 2, 3
```

You can't access individual elements to change them in the slice and if you do change the list you have to re-call isclice(..).

Comment: The code example is not even syntactically correct.