# Python loop to [:-1]

Tags: python, list, performance

So, I notice that calling `array[:-1]` is going to clone the array.

Say I have a large array with like 3000 elements in it.  I don't want it to be cloned as I iterate over it!  I just want to iterate to the 2nd last one.

```
for item in array[ :-1 ] :
  # do something with the item
```

So do I have to resort to a counter variable,

```
for c in range( 0, len( array ) - 1 ) :
  # do something with array[ c ]
```

or is there way to make/will `array[:-1]` syntax be efficient?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I create a "view" on a Python list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list)

Comment: Sadly, the "other question" misses out on `itertools` entirely. Thus I am *not* voting to close this question.

Comment: @pst wouldn't the "right thing to do" be to post a better answer on the other question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for item in itertools.islice(array, len(array) - 1):
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice
for item in islice(array, 0, len(array) - 1):
    # do something with item
```

This is about half of what you want; it eliminates the need to say `array[i]` but not the need to specify `len(array) - 1`.

For what it's worth, 3000 items is nothing to a modern computer, I wouldn't worry about the inefficiency unless your program is noticeably slow and you've profiled it to determine that this piece of code is a contributing factor.

Answer (score 2):

For when you don't want to/can't/don't know the length of the sequence:

```
def allbutlast(seq):
  it = iter(seq)
  el = next(it)
  for e in it:
    yield el
    el = e

for i in allbutlast([1, 2, 3]):
  print i
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this particular itertools function, but it looks like islice will do what you want

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice