# In-place sort of sublist

Tags: python, list, sorting, view, slice

Is it possible?  Obviously `x[1:-1].sort()` doesn't work because the slice is a copy.

Current workaround:

```
>>> x = [4, 3, 1, 2, 5]
>>> s = slice(1, -1)
>>> x[s] = sorted(x[s])
>>> x
[4, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Can I somehow get a *view* on a python list?

Comment: Related: [Can I create a “view” on a Python list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list)

Comment: See http://www.shaunlippy.org/blog/?p=77

Comment: There is now view for a list in python, afaik, as it exists for dict's (dict.viewkey etc.). I don't see any usecases for views on a list, so what do you mean by view & what should it provide? (```b=x``` would be some sort of a view, although it's quite useless).

Comment: `x[1:-1] = sorted(x[1:-1])` is quite neat in my opinion.  Why do you dislike it?

Comment: I guess you're right.  Taking the slice is O(n) but it's irrelevant because the sort is O(n*log(n)) anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) is an option:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 8, 90, 30, 5])
>>> x[2:].sort()
>>> x
array([ 1,  8,  5, 30, 90])
```

`numpy` array [slices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing) are always views of the original array.