# Python slice without copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

Is there a way to create a "slice view" of a sequence in Python 3 that behaves like a regular slice but does not create a copy of the sliced part of the sequence?  When the original sequence is updated, the "slice view" should reflect the update.

```
>>> l = list(range(100))
>>> s = Slice(l, 1, 50, 3)  # Should behave like l[1:50:3]
>>> s[1]
4
>>> l[4] = 'foo'
>>> s[1]  # Should reflect the updated value
'foo'
```

I can write my own `Slice` class that does this but I wanted to find out if there was a built-in way.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list  Not sure if something has come up in the intervening years, so not voting to close as a duplicate :-)

Comment: Could you specify what answers do you expect other than the provided in the linked question: custom Slice class, numpy, memoryview, generator (iterator)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [*islice*](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) from *itertools* library

**EDIT:**

I see where I misunderstood the question.
Well, there is no such thing. If you want to create your class, you'll have to:

1. Keep a reference to the original list in you *Slice* class
2. Define, *__iter__*,  *__getitem__* and *__setitem__* methods to work on the original list with index conversion

Comment: `islice` doesn't actually produce an indexable sequence - you need to materialize the iterator, at which point it will no longer be a view into the underlying sequence, but rather it's own sequence.