# How to get part of a list in Python without creating a new list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`. And I have a function, say, `Func(x)`. I know that if I do `Func(a)` then the reference of `a` will be passed into `Func(x)`. And if I do `Func(a[:])`, a new list will be created and passed into `Func(x)`.

So my question is: Is it possible to only pass the first three elements into `Func(x)` **by reference**, like `Func(a)` (I don't want to pass the whole list `a` into function due to certain reason)? If I do `Func(a[:4])` a new list will be created and that's what I want to avoid.

The only way I can think about is to pass `a` and the indexes into `Func(x)`, like `Func(a, start, end)`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a new list? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: This is a recursive function. If I create a new list every time, the stack will overflow.

Comment: Then pass the index as a parameter.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Thanks... That's also what I am thinking.

Comment: But I wouldn't worry about that, unless you get memory exception.

Comment: Basic slicing on numpy arrays generate views that meet your requirements, but there is nothing in the language or standard library

Comment: I would add that it's not _too_ hard to create your own [immutable list view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3485490/577088) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create a 'window' on a list, no.

Your only options are to create a slice, or to pass in start and end indices to the function and have the function honour those.

The latter is what the [`bisect` module functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) do for example; each function takes a `lo` and `hi` parameter that default to `0` and `len(list)` respectively:

```
def func(lst, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a second argument so that Func (a) becomes Func (a, n) where a is the reference to your array and n is the position in the array to which you want to evaluate to?

Something like:

```
Func (a, 2)
```

With that example the first three elements are evaluated.