# Python list slice as shallow copy

Tags: python, shallow-copy

```
foo = [1, 2, 3]  
foo[:][0] = 5
```

`foo` doesn't change, also:

```
import copy  
foo = [1, 2, 3]   
boo = copy.copy(foo)  
boo[0] = 5
```

Again, `foo[0]` stays the same.

Why? The shallow copy creates new list, but shouldn't `boo[0]`/`boo[1]`/`boo[2]` point to the same objects as `foo[0]`/`foo[1]`/`foo[2]`?

Comment: You are just reassigning what's stored at position 0 in your copy, why would that change the original?

Comment: I don't think the question that was marked duplicate is really a duplicate.  This question is not asking how to make a copy of a list, it's asking why a copy of a list doesn't work in the way the questioner expects.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list

Comment: @BrenBarn Sure. I felt that the OPs question was answered in the dupe So I used the hammer. I apologize for that. Regards.

Comment: Why would you expect foo to change when you are copying it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm just trying to understand how it works - I'm used to c++ mechanisms, which are very intuitive. Here the diffrence is subtle yet important and I'm trying to get it.

Comment: @JohnnyJohansson,  if you look at it logically, if `copy.copy` on a shallow list with no other mutable objects inside still meant changes were reflected in the original when the copy was mutated then copy.copy would basically be doing nothing. What differs in c++?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham doing nothing? it would create NEW object. My understanding was that if you would edit any of the items that were copied (boo[0/1/2]), the foo would change as well. But if you would for example append something to boo, foo wouldn't change.

Comment: yes but `foo` would be `boo` so  you would just have the same object not a new one.

Comment: no. they would only store 3 mutual integer objects - 1,2,3.

Comment: @JohnnyJohansson, lists store references to object, you are creating new objects/ints as ints are immutable, the only way you would be sharing references/objects would be if the objects inside the list were mutable, i.e other lists in which case you would `copy.deepcopy`. Apply the same logic to `[[1,2],[3,4]]`

Comment: Yes, and that's what I've been missing :d The diffrence between c++ and Python I struggle with is that in Python variable isn't really variable, it's a name assigned to an object, and this is very unusual for me so far.

Comment: @JohnnyJohansson,  there are a few gotchas in python especially coming from other languages  but overall it is a pretty easy language to use, everything is an object!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boo[0]` does point to the same object as `foo[0]`.  But doing `boo[0] = 5` does not modify the object referred to by `boo[0]`; it modifies the object referred to by `boo`.

Assigning to an element of a list modifies *the list* by changing what that element "points to".  It has no effect on the object that is pointed to.