# What does array[:] exactly do in this backtracking algorithm, or rather in Python?

Tags: python, indexing, syntax, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

So, I was solving(or rather, looking at the solution haha) a question on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/), and this was a solution to allow you to generate all possible permutations of an array with unique integers.

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:

        length = len(nums)
        results = []

        def backtrack(first_char_index):
            if first_char_index == length:
                # print(nums == nums[:])
                results.append(nums)

            for index in range(first_char_index, length):
                nums[first_char_index], nums[index] = nums[index], nums[first_char_index]
                backtrack(first_char_index + 1)
                nums[first_char_index], nums[index] = nums[index], nums[first_char_index]

        backtrack(0)
        return results
```

So, I was testing out the solution, and I realized that this solution only works if inside the `if` condition inside of the `backtrack` function, I use `results.append(nums[:])` instead of the above `results.append(nums)`.

So I initially figured that this was probably because `nums[:]` should be used because we need to generate a new copy, but then I had that print statement added before `results.append(nums)`, and found that all of the print statements gave me a `True` result.

I remember seeing a few solutions with this pattern of having `nums[:]` instead of `nums`, and would like to ask if anyone could shed light on what exactly does the extra [:] do? I know that it creates a new copy (i.e different object, but same value), but since it has the same value, why does result in a different result?

To illustrate this, the result with an input of `[1, 2, 3]` gives

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

when using `nums`, and

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

(the correct answer), when using `nums[:]`.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For some reason, this question is being recognized to be the same as others that are regarding deep/shallow copy. However, I guess what I'm asking here is that since `[:]` results in a new, different object with the **same value**, and with the fact that the value of `nums` and `nums[:]` is the same (it prints out to be the altered value), shouldn't it be appending an array with the altered value, instead of the original untouched `nums` array?

Comment: ``nums == nums[:]`` checks for *value equality*, not *object identity*. Try ``nums is nums[:]`` to check for copies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list slice as shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231577/python-list-slice-as-shallow-copy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nums and nums[:] have indeed the same value (that you check using ==), but the are different objects (that you can check using the 'is' keyword). Sequences are mutable, therefore you can change the values they contain without changing the object itself.
The [:] simply creates a copy of an existing sequence. This way you have a different object with all the values of the previous one

EDIT:
the reason is that, when you append nums to results, nums can still be changed even if it's inside results. Therefore the elements inside results will be changed everytime you change the original nums (in fact in the result all the values are identical). If you create a copy for each element you put in results, instead, the elements will all have different values.

Comment: Yes, i figured this is true from past experiments (i.e that's how i got the fact that it creates a new copy). However, their value is the same, so my question is why the array appended to results is not the same?

Comment: Because they are different objects (they therefore have different memory addresses).  This way, if you change the copy of nums you won't also change the original copy. If didn't use [:], by changing the copy of nums (ex. appending values) you would also change the original nums.

Comment: I am still not seeing why the "original values" are being appended to the results array. Sure, i get that nums[:] allow us to not edit the original array, but if the value of nums is the same as nums[:], shouldn't the value of the array appended to the results array be the _altered_ one instead of the _original_ one?

Comment: the reason is that, when you append nums to results, nums can still be changed even if it's inside results. Therefore the elements inside results will be changed everytime you change the original nums (in fact in the result all the values are identical). If you create a copy for each element you put in results, instead, the elements will all have different values.

Comment: Okay, this answers my question! If you'll edit and add this to the answer above I'll mark it as correct :) Thanks!