# Recursive Selection sort to return a descending list in python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, recursion

I'd been working through a problem, to sort the elements in a descending order through a recursive approach, the code is as follows..

```
import operator

def do_stuff(elem_list):

    if not elem_list:
        return None

    max_index , max_element = max(enumerate(elem_list) , key = operator.itemgetter(1))
    elem_list[max_index],elem_list[0] = elem_list[0],elem_list[max_index]

    return do_stuff(elem_list[1:])

p_list = [4,2,3,5,1]
do_stuff(p_list)
print(p_list)
```

Output -

```
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

And I can't seem to figure wherein lies the problem and why won't I get the desired output ?

Comment: `elem_list[1:]` is a completely separate list from `elem_list`.

Comment: It is but a slice of the elem_list. After the function, upon printing the list again, should it not give me the correct stuff ?

Comment: Try fiddling with `l1 = [1, 2, 3]; l2 = l1[1:]` in interactive mode and see what effect changing one list has on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix your problem by adding an extra parameter, since you seem to be using a recursive implementation of [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), you need some way to track the next open place to swap values in the list.

```
import operator
def sortl(l, last):
    # base case
    if last + 1 >= len(l):
         return l
    # find the max index (mi) and max value in the list
    mi, _ = max(enumerate(l[last:]), key = operator.itemgetter(1))
    mi += last # caculate the offset in the sublist
    l[mi], l[last] = l[last], l[mi] # swap the values

    # recursive call
    return sortl(l, last + 1)
```

By using "last + 1" every time, you are able to simulate using the underlying sublist since calling do_stuff([some_list[1:]) wont work

Comment: Thanks a lot. That does it perfectly !!

Comment: You can give `last` a default value of `0`, so that you can call `sortl` with just a list and it will still work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Python's slices are not true references to the underlying list. See: [Can I create a "view" on a Python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list)