# Passing a mutable variable to a second variable doesn't always work as expected. Why? Is there a workaround to keep the original variable reference?

Tags: python

Passing a mutable variable to a second variable doesn't always work as expected.  Why?  Is there a workaround to keep the original variable reference?

Example:

```
>>> listA = [10,11,12,13,14]

# this works as I would expect it:
>>> ref = listA
>>> ref[0] = 20
>>> listA
[20, 11, 12, 13, 14]

# but this doesn't
>>> ref = listA[1:3]    # still making reference to a mutable (only part of it)
>>> ref
[11, 12]
>>> ref[0]=30
>>> listA
[20, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: You do **not** create a *view* with `listA[1:3]`, but a **copy** of that part.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to create a view from a slice (and assign that view to a variable name)?  E.g. emulate numpy's behaviour.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3485475/67579), there is no *builtin* view afaik.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption in the comment:

> `# still making reference to a mutable (only part of it)`

Is **wrong**.

When you use ***slicing* on `list`s**, you create a **shallow copy**, **not** a *view*. So those are two independent lists that operate differently. Therefore changes to `ref` will not reflect on `listA` and vice versa.

Note that the **elements in the list**, are still the same. So the memory will look like:

```
         +-------------------+         +-------+
listA -> |       list        |  ref -> |  list |
         +---+---+---+---+---+         +---+---+
         | o | o | o | o | o |         | o | o |
         +-|-+-|-+-|-+-|-+-|-+         +-|-+-|-+
           v   |   |   v   v             |   |
           20  |   |   13  14            |   |
               |   v                     |   |
               v   12 <------------------|---/
               11 <----------------------/
```

Here that does not matter, since `int`s are immutable.  But if you would for instance call a method on an element of `listA` that changes the state of that object, the change will also reflect when you refer to that element through `ref[0]` for instance.

This behavior is **not always** the case, for instance **`numpy` arrays use *views*** when  slicing is done. For instance:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> b = a[1:3] # slicing in numpy generates a "view"
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b
array([1, 2])
>>> b[0] = 5
>>> a
array([0, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b
array([5, 2])
```

You should always consult the documentation, like [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) for numpy arrays:

> (...)
>
> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always **views** of the original array.
>
> (...)

## Creating a `listview`

You could construct a view on a list, by defining a class like:

```
class listview:

    def __init__(self,data,frm=None,len=None):
        self.data = data
        self.frm = frm
        self.len = len

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        if self.frm is not None:
            idx += self.frm
        if self.len is not None and idx >= self.len:
            raise Exception('Index out of range!')
        return self.data[idx]

    def __setitem__(self,idx,value):
        if self.frm is not None:
            idx += self.frm
        if self.len is not None and idx >= self.len:
            raise Exception('Index out of range!')
        self.data[idx] = value

    def __len__(self):
        frm = 0
        if self.frm is not None:
            frm = self.frm
        if self.len is not None:
            return min(self.len,len(self.data)-frm)
        return len(self.data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'listview(%s,%s,%s)'%(self.data,self.frm,self.len)

    # ... and so on
```

Then you can construct a view like:

```
>>> listA = [10,11,12,13,14]
>>> ref = listview(listA,1,2)
>>> ref[0] = 5
>>> listA
[10, 5, 12, 13, 14]
```