# How to check if the first half of a list is equal to the other efficiently?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, equality

I need to check if a Python list consists of two equal halves. For example, this list does:

```
[6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2]
```

and this doesn't

```
[6, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6]
```

I've tried this check: `len(lst) % 2 == 0 and lst[:len(lst)//2] == lst[len(lst)//2:]` but it seems to be too slow for bigger lists. Any other solutions?

Comment: The solution is about slicing without copying, but python doesn't seem a builtin or standard way of doing that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list

Comment: Can you guarantee that the input list will always have an even length?

Comment: @PM 2Ring: I use an extra check that `len(lst) % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to do the check without creating the two sublists. It might be faster for really big lists.

```
n = len(lst)//2
all(lst[i]==lst[i+n] for i in range(n))
```

If you want to also check that your list is of even length, you could also add

```
len(lst)%2==0
```

as a condition.

Comment: Gah, indices. Much better.

Comment: Bug detected - doesn't work for a list of odd length

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm surprised that indices are better than islice. And (I think) you don't need 2 islices: you just need the islice for the back half and use the whole list for the front half, since `zip` will stop when the shortest sequence terminates.

Comment: @Leon: how so? `//` **floors** so I don't see how `n + n` would ever be greater than `n`. And the OP never defined what is the right res

Comment: @MartijnPieters A list of odd length **never** consists of two equal halves.

Comment: So to handle odd length `lst`: immediately return False. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters What will this code tell for the following list: `[1, 1, 0]`? In case of an odd length, the last element is ignored.

Comment: @PM2Ring islice iterates over half the list *first*; it doesn't use indexing to skip over the first half.

Comment: @Leon: sure, different result, but there's no constraint in the question about handling odd lengths. Just add a `len(lst) % 2` test first to return `False` or raise an exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't mean that the solution is wrong to the extent of being unfixable. Just wanted to bring the author's attention to the overlooked case

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, of course. In general, it's impossible for `islice` to skip to an arbitrary point in an iterable, so it _has_ to iterate. D'oh! :)

Comment: This is slightly better, but not much.. I think I'll need to use a different data structure.