# Change a list element by changing its slice element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Consider:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

When I slice it I get a new list `b`:

```
b = a[:2]
```

If I now alter list `b`:

```
b[0] = 0
```

I get `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [0, 2]`.  Why doesn't the `a` list get altered as well? I know that slicing creates a new list object, but why is it not the object of the same elements as the inital object?  How can I slice `a` so that:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[:2]
b[0] = 0
```

Results in `a = [0, 2, 3]` and `b = [0, 2]`.

Comment: Because ```b = a[:2]``` is making a copy of list a upto the 3rd index

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485475/can-i-create-a-view-on-a-python-list

Answer (score 0):

You could try slicing later:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b[0] = 0
b = b[:2]
print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 3] [0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation `[:2]` is making a shallow copy of the list `a` upto the 3rd index.

For instance, if you would have ever seen programmers doing `[:]` while iterating over a list, they are creating the shallow copy of the list. Similarly, the above notation makes a copy of the list upto the 3rd index so you get something as:

```
[1, 2]
```

To get the result, you can do:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b[0] =0
```

In here `b = a` is not making a copy the list. Both `a, b` point to the same list in the memory.

If you change either of the 2, it will reflect in both of them. Later, you can slice `b` by `[:2]`