Getting a flat view of a nested list
In Python, is it possible to get a flat view of a list of lists that dynamically adapts to changes to the original, nested list?
To be clear, I am not looking for a static snapshot, but for a view that reflects changes.
Further, the sub-lists should not be restricted to a primitive type, but be able to contain arbitrary objects, and not tied to a static size, but be allowed to shrink or expand freely.
Simple example:
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["d", "e", "f"]
view = flat_view([a, b])
# `view` should show ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
b[0] = "x"
# `view` should show ["a", "b", "c", "x", "e", "f"]

The implementation of flat_view() is what I'm looking for.

I'm unaware of any "native" ability to do this.  Historically, you reach for a memoryview to get this kind of read-only view into a Buffer, but there isn't a ready-made flat-view in Python's standard library.

This reminds me of Go slices. In Python, when you create a new list, it is not a pointer/ref to the original.

That is true of slices that it creates a copy, @Mr.Polywhirl but lists are byref and modifying a variable that points to the same list as another will modify it for both holders.

Creating a view on a single list is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485475/3001761, also flattening seems quite specific to your use case. It's unclear what functionality you'd need beyond just visually displaying the flattened form (iterating, indexing, ...?) You may also want to look into weakly referencing the underlying data.

You would need to create a class that holds a reference to the original lists.
You don't want a copy of the lists, you just need a reference. This class knows how to access and update the values at each of the lists it holds.
You can access any item in the list in O(log n) search complexity (binary search) without using any additional memory to store a flattend list.
Implementation
Imports for types to follow:
from typing import Any, Callable, Iterable, List, Tuple, Union

If you want the view to listen to changes in the underlying lists, you will need to create an ListWrapper that can delegate to the underlying list and notify the view that things changed in the lists.
We want to make sure self._notify() is called whenever a list changes.
class ListWrapper:
    def __init__(self, lst: List[Any]):
        self._list: List[Any] = lst
        self.callbacks: List[Callable[[], None]] = []

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Any:
        return self._list[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index: int, value: Any) -> None:
        self._list[index] = value
        self._notify()

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._list)

    def append(self, item: Any) -> None:
        self._list.append(item)
        self._notify()

    def extend(self, iterable: Iterable[Any]) -> None:
        self._list.extend(iterable)
        self._notify()

    def insert(self, index: int, item: Any) -> None:
        self._list.insert(index, item)
        self._notify()

    def remove(self, item: Any) -> None:
        self._list.remove(item)
        self._notify()

    def pop(self, index: int = -1) -> Any:
        item = self._list.pop(index)
        self._notify()
        return item

    def clear(self) -> None:
        self._list.clear()
        self._notify()

    def _notify(self) -> None:
        for callback in self.callbacks:
            callback()

    def add_callback(self, callback: Callable[[], None]) -> None:
        self.callbacks.append(callback)

Here is a class which provides a "flat view" of multiple lists, where updates to the original lists are reflected in the flat view.
class FlatView:
    def __init__(self, lists: List[ListWrapper]) -> None:
        self.lists = lists
        self.update_lengths()
        for lst in self.lists:
            lst.add_callback(self.update_lengths)

    def update_lengths(self) -> None:
        self.sub_lengths = self._compute_overall_length()

    def _compute_overall_length(self) -> List[int]:
        lengths = [0]
        for lst in self.lists:
            lengths.append(lengths[-1] + len(lst))
        return lengths

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Any:
        if index < 0 or index >= len(self):
            raise IndexError("list index out of range")
        list_index = self._find_list_index(index)
        sublist_index = index - self.sub_lengths[list_index]
        return self.lists[list_index][sublist_index]

    def _find_list_index(self, index: int) -> int:
        # Binary search to find the list that contains the index
        low, high = 0, len(self.sub_lengths) - 1
        while low < high:
            mid = (low + high) // 2
            if self.sub_lengths[mid] <= index < self.sub_lengths[mid + 1]:
                return mid
            elif index < self.sub_lengths[mid]:
                high = mid
            else:
                low = mid + 1
        return low

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.sub_lengths[-1]

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return repr([item for lst in self.lists for item in lst])

Usage
The following wrapper function creates a FlatView instance for the provided list of lists.
We wrap each list in a ListWrapper so that we can attach a callback function to update the view's overall lengths that are used to access the data.
def flat_view(lists: List[List[Any]]) -> Tuple[FlatView, List[ListWrapper]]:
    wrappers = [ListWrapper(lst) for lst in lists]
    return FlatView(wrappers), wrappers

Here is how you would use it. Please note that we need to modify the wrappers for the view to understand how the lists change.
For example, b[0] = "x" would not work.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = ["a", "b", "c"]
    b = ["d", "e", "f"]
    view, [a_wrapper, b_wrapper] = flat_view([a, b])
    
    print(view)                # Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    
    b_wrapper[0] = "x"
    print(view)                # Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'e', 'f']
    
    print(view[3], len(view))  # Output: 'x' 6
    
    a_wrapper.append("y")
    print(view, len(view))     # Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'y', 'x', 'e', 'f'] 7

    print(a, len(a))           # Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'y'] 4
    print(b, len(b))           # Output: ['x', 'e', 'f'] 3


Not the topic of the question, but IMO the docstrings are overly verbose, making the code actually more difficult to read. e.g. you could just add a type annotation like -> FlatView and get rid of Returns: FlatView: An instance of the FlatView class.

I like this answer as it solves the question, but I think paying a O(N) cost for indexing is poor and could be improved.

@MaximilianBurszley There are trade-offs for memory usage vs performance. I think the O(log n) meets in the middle.

The question states that "sub-lists should not be [...] tied to a static size, but be allowed to shrink or expand freely." This is not provided when computing sub_lengths only once on initialization.

"If you wanted O(1) search complexity, you would need to store a copy of the flattened list." Copying would mean that it is not a view anymore, so not sure why that phrase is in the answer.

@mara004 ok, I removed it and made sure that the view knows about changes. The caveat is that you need to modify the wrappers.

@Mr.Polywhirl Thanks!

You can write a generator that flattens the structure contained in it. This will reflect all the changes to the structure, so will behave like view you need.
class FlatView:
    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.sequence = sequence
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from FlatView.flatten(self.sequence)
    @staticmethod
    def flatten(item):
        for i in item:
            if hasattr(i, '__iter__') and not isinstance(i, str):
                yield from FlatView.flatten(i)
            else:
                yield i
    
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["d", "e", "f"]
c = [a,b]
view = FlatView(c)
print(list(view)) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
b[0] = "x"
print(list(view)) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'e', 'f']
c.append(["g", "h", "i"])
print(list(view)) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
print(c)          # [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]


I think this misses one point, and that's being able to index into the view itself to modify members.  You would need to logically treat each list as a contiguous part of a larger list.  I might be extrapolating that as a requirement, though.  @OP would need to clarify.

Thinking about the meaning of a view, it's probably not necessary to modify the members, but I think I would expect the ability to do view[7] == "g".

@MaximilianBurszley What if your original structure contains non-ordered objects - "view should not be restricted to a primitive type, but be able to handle arbitrary objects". For example, if any of the sub-containers is a set instead of a list, indexing into it is meaningless.

Ah, that's sensible.  I guess it's up to OP discretion what they meant.

@matszwecja @MaximilianBurszley Sorry for the confusion. With "should not be restricted to a primitive type, but be able to handle arbitrary objects" I meant the values in the containers, not the containers themselves, so as not to get some numpy'ish fixed dtype. Also, I'm not looking for recursive flattening, but just for depth=1 flattening.

This simple class accepts arbitrary nested sequences and at each access it computes the indices referencing the item to be returned.
from collections.abc import Sequence

def generate_refs(nested, prefix):
    for i, value in enumerate(nested):
        idx = prefix + [i] 
        if isinstance(value, Sequence) and not isinstance(value, str):
            yield from generate_refs(value, idx)
        else:
            yield idx 

class FlatView:
    def __init__(self, nested):
        self._nested = nested

    def __getitem__(self, n): 
        if not isinstance(n, int):
            raise TypeError("integer indices only")
        if n < 0:
            raise IndexError("negative indices not supported")
        gen = generate_refs(self._nested, [])
        try:
            for _ in range(n+1):
                ref = next(gen)
        except StopIteration:
            raise IndexError("index out of range") from None
        # print(f"debug: position [{n}]: {ref}")
        value = self._nested
        for i in ref:
            value = value[i]
        return value

a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["d", "e", "f"]
test = [a, [b, "g", "h"], "i"]

fw = FlatView(test)
print("nested:", test)
print("flattened:", list(fw))
print("item [5]:", fw[5])
a.extend(["c2", "c3"]) ; print("extended the list 'a'")
print("item [5]:", fw[5])

Output:
nested: [['a', 'b', 'c'], [['d', 'e', 'f'], 'g', 'h'], 'i']
flattened: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
item [5]: f
extended the list 'a'
item [5]: d



The question requests that "the sub-lists should not be restricted to a static size, but be allowed to expand or shrink freely.", which is not provided when computing refs only once on initialization.

@mara004 I have updated my answer to do computation at access time.
