# List slice python

Tags: python, list, sorting, slice, quicksort

I am attempting to quicksort a list and want to do so in place.

I have the following code and want to know in general (this problem comes up often for me as I try to solve list problems in place on the actual list rather than a complicated sequence of returns or using weird indices) can a list slice ever allow me to affect the list from which it's derived? Are there larger ramifications for doing something like this?

```
def partition(A,l,r):
    p=A[l]
    i=l+1
    print(A)
    for j in range(l+1,r):
        if A[j]<p:
            save=A[i]
            A[i]=A[j]
            A[j]=save
            i+=1
    save=A[i-1]
    A[i-1]=A[l]
    A[l]=save
    return i-1
def quickSort(A,n):
    if n>1:
        split=partition(A,0,n)
        quickSort(A[:split],len(A[:split]))
        quickSort(A[split+1:],len(A[split+1:]))
        print(A)
    return A
A=[3,4,5,2,10,7,6,9,1]
print(quickSort(A,len(A)))
```

Comment: A list slice is always a copy. That's why `l[:]` is the idiom for making a copy of a whole list.

Comment: So is there any way to get code like this to work? Can I actually point to the elements in my list A using a list slice somehow?

Comment: there's a disrepancy in the number of arguments of  your `quickSort` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference to Part of List - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788608/reference-to-part-of-list-python)

Comment: A tip: idiomatic swapping in python without temporary variables: `A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]`

Comment: Except I am not looking to copy my list in another variable, I literally want only a portion of it to go into the recursive call

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "I literally want only a portion of it to go into the recursive call", slicing a list *always* returns a copy, so whatever you want, you cannot do that with slices. You will have to keep track of indices.

Comment: look at the comment below...exactly the type of functionality I was looking for

Comment: Then you are no longer sorting a *list*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) lets you assign to slices in a way that is reflected in the original array (`numpy` slices return [views](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view)):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(range(10))
print(a)   # [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
b = a[3:7]
print(b)   # [3 4 5 6]
b[0] = 33
print(b)   # [33  4  5  6]
print(a)   # [ 0  1  2 33  4  5  6  7  8  9]
```

a slice of a python `list` always returns a copy so you would have to write a view on a list yourself...

Comment: Man you are awesome! works perfectly and I would have never thought of using numpy for a task like this. Thank you thank you thank you.